Integrating Clever IDP (OIDC) with Keycloak
I am new to Keycloak, and I am trying to integrate the external identity provider Clever into Keycloak. I read through Clever's documentation here: https://dev.clever.com/docs/oidc-implementation, seeing that they are OIDC compliant. They show an example for how they integrate with AWS Cognito, so I tried to integrate them with Keycloak. However, after registering Clever as an OIDC provider, I am getting errors on Keycloak when attempting to login with Clever. After logging in on the Clever page, then being redirected back to Keycloak, I get this error: Unexpected error when authenticating with identity provider, accompanied by the following log in the Docker container I'm running keycloak out of.
Failed to make identity provider oauth callback: org.keycloak.broker.provider.IdentityBrokerException: No token from server.

Reading through Clever's doc's, this URL: https://clever.com/oauth/tokens, is what is used to get a token for the OIDC flow. This error makes it seem like Keycloak isn't able to get a token response from the URL. If anyone has any experience or tips with integrating Keycloak with Clever or OIDC, any tips would be appreciated! Thanks
Because Clever is OIDC compliant, my setup on Keycloak involved putting in the appropriate values in the Realm > Identity Providers > OpenID Connect v1 form. On the form, I put in Clever's OIDC well-know url, and the client id and secret associated with my app. I followed a similar procedure when integrating with Azure AD, and that seemed to work. I wonder if I am missing any steps, or if Clever simply doesn't integrate with Keycloak.
